# QGIS 3.16 How to get a Shapefile-Layer with number of features in Brackets (Layer-Tree)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have received a polygon layer as a shapefile in which the number of features is shown in brackets in the name. (QGIS3.16.10)
When I copied the layer, this feature disappeared and I have searched unsuccessfully to find it in the settings. Does anyone know how I can make it work?

[image: it should look like this]

Comment: Right-click the layer name and select `Show Feature Count`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I searched in the submenus ... Didn't think it would work that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the layer name and select Show Feature Count - Thank You Matt